# Seq2Seq model in text-to-text

Tags: nlp, seq2seq, simpletransformers

Welcome,
I tried to extract the tables from the pdf, but if the table does not contain any bounds, then it doesn't get extracted, so I want to extract the text and the Seq2Seq model predicts the columns and rows,
How can I do that?!

I'm trying to train a Seq2Seq model from `simpletransformers` but it's not working,

this is my training data, it's like this:
[image: training data]

this is my Seq2Seq code:

```
model_args = Seq2SeqArgs()
model_args.num_train_epochs = 100
model_args.evalAuate_generated_text = True
model_args.evaluate_during_training = True
model_args.evaluate_during_training_verbose = True
model_args.max_length = 4096
model_args.train_batch_size = 16
model_args.eval_batch_size = 16
model_args.no_save = True
model_args.length_penalty = 3.0

model = Seq2SeqModel(
    encoder_decoder_type="bart",
    encoder_decoder_name="facebook/bart-large",
    args=model_args,
    use_cuda=True,
)
```

and this is the output I got:
[image: output]